# Wofür steht die Abkürzung ARBL.I.R.?

Tags: abbreviation, austrian

Ich habe auf einem Grabstein (in der Steiermark) unter dem Namen die Abkürzung *ARBL.I.R.* gesehen.

Es handelt sich dabei sehr wahrschienlich um eine Berufsbezeichnung, da bei einer zweiten Person in dem Grab *TISCHLERM.I.R.* steht. Was *Tischlermeister im Ruhestand* bedeutet.

*I.R* steht für *im Ruhestand*, ich habe aber keine Ahnung wofür *ARBL.* stehen könnte.
Das einzige was mir dazu einfällt wäre *Arbeitslos*. Ich habe aber keine Ahnung warum man das auf den Grabstein schreiben sollte.

Bei der Verstorbenen handelt es sich um eine Frau die 1978 verstorben ist.

Hier ein Foto des Grabsteins:
[image: Grabstein Foto]

Comment: Woher wissen Sie, dass *i.R.* hier nicht - wie ja auch heute noch üblich - *im Ruhestand* bedeutet?

Comment: @johnl: Für mich ist in dem Zusammenhang *in Ruhe* und *im Ruhestand* synonym. Soll ich das editieren?

Comment: "in Ruhe" und "im Ruhestand" ´sind nicht synonym. Nach Ende seines Berufslebens ist man im Ruhestand, in Ruhe kann man immer wieder mal sein.

Comment: Na ja, *Arbeitslose im Ruhestand* sollte es ja nicht geben, insofern versperrt das ja ein Wenig diese Lesart. Ich habe bei *Arbl* übrigens spontan an *Arbeitsleiterin* gedacht. Ich kenne das zwar nicht als Rang, es lässt sich aber belegen, siehe Google Books oder, mit weniger falschen Treffern, https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/search?query=all%3AArbeitsleiterin (für die männliche Form findet man natürlich mehr). Das vielleicht nur als Idee.

Comment: *Arbeitsleiter* war übrigens auch ein offenbar gängiger Titel in der (DDR-?)Wissenschaftsstruktur, Angaben wie "wissenschaftliche Arbeitsleiterin am Zentralinstitut für Geschichte der Akademie der Wissenschaften der DDR" sind mannigfach auf Google Books zu finden. Vielleicht so etwas wie heute Arbeitsgruppenleiterin. https://www.google.de/search?q=%22arbeitsleiterin%22+ddr&hl=en&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJBR4E78G-xMgfP9Sxf_Y-53fPyyw:1632130077524&ei=HVRIYdiWH_D_7_UPw7qbgAE&start=0&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiYmf2rno3zAhXw_7sIHUPdBhA4ChDy0wN6BAgBEDw&biw=1920&bih=880&dpr=1

Comment: @johnl: Der Grabstein steht in der Steimermark/Österreich. Einen DDR Bezug halte ich daher für unwahrscheinlich.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die Abkürzung könnte "Arbeitslehrerin im Ruhestand" bedeuten. Arbeitslehrerinnen waren Lehrerinnen im Bereich der Werkerziehung und Hauswirtschaft. Im [österreichischen Recht](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/GeltendeFassung.wxe?Abfrage=Bundesnormen&Gesetzesnummer=10009281&FassungVom=2017-03-31) findet sich folgende Aufgabenbeschreibung:

> Die **Bildungsanstalten für Arbeitslehrerinnen** haben (...) die Aufgabe, **Lehrerinnen für den Unterricht in Werkerziehung (für Mädchen) und Hauswirtschaft** an den allgemeinbildenden Pflichtschulen heranzubilden, die nach Berufsgesinnung, Berufswissen und Berufskönnen geeignet sind, die Aufgaben dieses Unterrichtes zu erfüllen.

<sup>Quelle: Verordnung des Bundesministeriums für Unterricht vom 22. Juni 1964,
mit welcher der Lehrplan der Bildungsanstalt für Arbeitslehrerinnen
erlassen wird; Bekanntmachung der Lehrpläne für den
Religionsunterricht an dieser Schule.</sup>

Die Berufsbezeichnung ist zwar nicht mehr aktuell: der [österreichische Lehrplan für Arbeitslehrerinnen von 1980](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/Dokumente/Bundesnormen/NOR40007388/NOR40007388.html) (der den Aufgabenbereich der Arbeitslehrerinnen ebenso wie oben zitiert beschreibt) wurde jedenfalls [im Jahr 2017 durch die Schulrechtsbereinigungsverordnung aufgehoben](https://www.ris.bka.gv.at/eli/bgbl/II/2017/90). Aber im Todesjahr 1978 war die Berufsbezeichnung noch absolut gebräuchlich.

Comment: Das klingt sehr plausibel. Ich werde mit dem Akzeptieren noch etwas warten. Vielleicht hat jemand noch eine Quelle mit der Abkürzung. Einstweilen +1 von mir.

Answer (score 3):

Auf Anregung von guidot mache ich aus meinen Kommentaren eine eigene Antwort. Das Verdienst, die Abkürzung plausibel erklärt zu haben, liegt aber ganz klar bei tohuwawohu.

Die Arbürzung "ARBL" ist nicht eindeutig. Sie wurde (und wird?) auch in Österreich verwendet. Mit einiger Sicherheit steht sie für "ARBEITSL...". Es kommen also in Frage

1. "ARBEITSLOS" (vgl. [hier](https://download.e-bookshelf.de/download/0012/0052/16/L-O-0012005216-0032282439.pdf) - im Text nach"ARBL" suchen).
   Das passt nicht, weil sie im Ruhestand war und man außerdem auf einem Grabstein eher mit Stolz auf einen früheren Beruf hinweist und die Person nicht als arbeitslos "outet".
2. ARBEITSLEHRERIN; siehe tohuwawohus Antwort.
   Einen Beleg findet man auf einer Website der [Friedrich-Alexander-Universität Erlangen-Nürnberg](https://www.fau.de/fau/rechtsgrundlagen/pruefungsordnungen/lehramtsstudiengaenge/#beruf-und-wirtschaft), wenn man den Punkt "Beruf und Wirtschaft" aufklappt. Dort befinden sich drei pdfs mit der Abkürzung **ArbL** im Titel. Beispielsweise
   *Fachstudien- und Prüfungsordnung für das Fach Arbeitslehre im  Lehramtsstudiengang an der Friedrich-Alexander-Universität Erlangen-Nürnberg (FAU) – FPO LA ArbL –*
   Diese [Fundstelle](https://www.zobodat.at/pdf/MittNatVerSt_22_I-XV.pdf) - nach "ARBEITSLEHRERIN" suchen - zeigt weiterhin, dass die Berufsbezeichnung recht alt ist (sie taucht im *Personalstand des naturwissenschaftlichen Vereines  für  Steiermark im  Vereinsjahre 1885* auf) und daher auch gut zu einer Dame aus der Steiermark mit Geburtsjahr 1892 passt.

Für die Variante "ARBEITSLEITERIN" (vgl. Kommentar von johnl) konnte ich keinen Beleg finden. Diese Bezeichnung scheint in DDR verwendet worden zu sein und passt daher auch nicht zu einer Österreicherin, die 1978 im Alter vom 86 Jahren gestorben ist.

Zum Abschluss noch eine Vermutung, warum die Abkürzung ARBL verwendet wurde: Entweder war sie allgemein üblich und bekannt - oder sie wurde nur aus Gründen der optischen Gestaltung des Grabsteins gewählt. Das volle Wort ARBEITSLEHRERIN oder auch ARBEITSLEHR. bzw. ARB.LEHR. hätte den Namen SEIDL in den Hintergrund gedrängt.

Comment: Ich denke generell nicht, dass es so entscheidend ist, ob für solche Abkürzungen Belege auffindbar sind. Abkürzungen auf einem Grabstein (oder in einer Kontaktanzeige) sind oftmals Spontanabkürzungen, die man (gezwungenermaßen) setzt, wenn jedes Zeichen Geld kostet oder es ein Zeichenlimit gibt, keine etablierten Abkürzungen, über die unbedingt bereits Sprecherkonsens bestünde. Sie werden darauf selektiert, im jeweiligen Kontext von den jeweils Angesprochenen verstanden zu werden. Bei der Rekonstruktion erweisen sich dabei eben manche Lesarten im jeweiligen Kontext als plausibler als andere.

Comment: @johnl Ich stimme zu, dass Belege nicht so entscheidend sind, weil ja tohuwawohu eine überzeugende Deutung geben konnte. Dass es sich um eine Spontanabkürzung handelt, mag sein. Ähnliches sagt auch Paul Frost. Die Begründung "Sie werden darauf selektiert, im jeweiligen Kontext von den jeweils Angesprochenen verstanden zu werden" trifft m.E. nicht zu. Für alle, die sie kannten, ist die Information überflüssig; alle anderen Angesprochenen (d.h. sonstige Friedhofsbesucher) werden vor ein Rätsel gestellt.